# What regular expression can be used with grep, flag -E, to display lines from a text file with ONLY an odd number of characters?

Tags: linux, regex, grep

I am trying to search through a text file using grep and display lines with only an odd number of characters. I need to use the command:

```
grep -E 'some regex' filename.txt
```

but I cannot figure out how to properly format the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `^.(..)*$`.

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  .         # any character but newline
  (..)*     # group 1, 2 any character, 0 or more times
$           # end of line
```

**In action:**

```
~$cat file.txt
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456

~$grep -E '^.(..)*$' file.txt
1
123
12345
```

Comment: That worked, thank you!